# Form a sequence of values from strings

Tags: java

I need to iterate through each element in a matrix like structure. For example,

```
SeatingType Model Back  Mech 
1              6   120   58
               7   121   59
               8
```

In java values will be coming as parameters as string in comma seperated values  Eg SeatingTpe (1), Model (6,7,8) etc.

I need to get the result as

```
1,6,120,58
1,6,120,59
1,6,121,58
1,6,121,59
1,7,120,58
1,7,120,59
1,7,121,58
1,7,121,59
1,8,120,58
1,8,120,59
1,8,121,58
1,8,121,59
```

Please note that Model, Back and Mech could be null.So in case Model values is null, then output should be 1,6,58 and 1,6,59 so on. Any help plz

As a headstart, I tried by looping through from last element (in this case 'Mech')> But that is very tedious. Any other approach ? I have provided only 4 atributes over here. But the reqmnt is for 11 attributes. I was hoping if I could get solution for 4 atributes, that could be applied for rest 7

Comment: Did you try anything before posting the question?

Comment: As a headstart, I tried by looping through from last element (in this case 'Mech')> But that is very tedious. Any other approach ?

Comment: Recursion fits this problem like a glove.

Comment: There is a contradiction in your explanation concerning null values. Probably you mean "in case Back is null". Please give an example for null values as well. To be clear, please mark nulls as <null>.

Comment: null values means user has not selected any values. If for eg Back is null then back = "", seating type = 1, model = 6,7,8 MEch = 58,59 . This will be the 4 parameters to the function in java

Comment: Because you only have 4 attributes, 4 nested loops would fit as well, this way you can produce the Cartesian Product.

Comment: No @GaborSch  There are 11 attributes to be exact. For loop is goin to be very tedious

Comment: You asked the same question 2 days ago with exact same contents. Do check the reason why it was closed. Please see [ask] to get an answer. You need to show what you have tried.

Comment: @SanjaiPalliyil That's still much simpler in my opinion than a recursion. Also the code is understandable for an average programmer who don't implement recursive algorithms day-by-day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through 4 loops:

```
List<String> seatTypeValues = ...
List<String> modelValues = ...
List<String> backValues = ...
List<String> mechValues = ...

if (seatTypeValues.isEmpty()) { seatTypeValues.add(null); }
... // all 4 lists

for(String seatType : seatTypeValues) {
  for(String model : modelValues) {
    for(String back : backValues) {
      for(String mech : mechValues) {
        // print the CSV
        if (seatType != null) {
          writer.write(seatType);
        }
        if (model != null) {
          writer.write(',');
          writer.write(model);
        }
        if (back != null) {
          writer.write(',');
          writer.write(back);
        }
        if (mech != null) {
          writer.write(',');
          writer.write(mech);
        }
        writer.write("\r\n");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Gabor . What if the Model or back is empty. How do we handle. doesnt enter for loop rite

Comment: The line `if (seatTypeValues.isEmpty()) { seatTypeValues.add(null); }` will add a null value to the list, it will enter the loop once.

Comment: Will you accept the answer?